# how i can add the version and encoding to a xml file using TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe

i want to add the version and encodig to a xml file created with `TXMLDocument` component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

curently i'm doing this

```
XmlDoc   :=TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
XmlDoc.Version:='1.0';
XMLDoc.Encoding:='utf-8';
```

but i receive an acces violation in this line

```
XmlDoc.Version:='1.0';
```

how i can add the version and encoding?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you must set the `Active` property to `True` before to modify the XML document properties.

```
XmlDoc   :=TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
XmlDoc.Active:=True;
XmlDoc.Version:='1.0';
XMLDoc.Encoding:='utf-8';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you construct a `TXMLDocument` with a `nil` Owner, the new instance uses reference counting to maintain its lifetime, so you MUST assign it to an `IXMLDocument` variable to maintain the reference count correctly or else the instance will be freed prematurely. Do not use a `TXMLDocument` variable in that situation.  This is documented behavior, and would account for your AV.  When working with dynamic instances of `TXMLDocument`, it is better to use the `NewXMLDocument()` and `LoadXML...()` functions instead.